# Bash script different ouput when run as cronjob

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

When I try to run the following basic script as a cronjob it returns a different result than when I run it manually.

When I run it manually is returns "OK..." when I run it as a cronjob it returns "WARNING..."

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script will check the public IP address of your server and compare it against a recent check
# The purpose of this script is to notify you when your public IP address has changed for remote access purposes
#
# Start by defining a couple variables (One checks the last IP, one checks the current)
#
last_ip=$(more /tmp/last_ip_check.txt)
current_ip=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)
date=$(date)
#
#
if [ "$last_ip" == "$current_ip" ]
then
  echo "$date OK: Your IP address hasn't changed" >> /tmp/ip_address_changes
else
  echo "WARNING: Your IP address has changed to $current_ip" | mailx -s "Plex IP Address Change" emailaddress@domain.com
  echo "$date WARNING: Your IP address has changed to $current_ip" >> /tmp/ip_address_changes
fi
#
# Dump the output of your ip check into the /tmp file for the next check
#
echo "$current_ip" > /tmp/last_ip_check.txt
#
```

I've sources bash_profile and adding a different path to the script with no luck. Also as a note last_ip and current_ip are the same string/address.

Comment: Why are you using the pager `more` in `$(...)` instead if `$(cat /tmp/last_ip_check.txt)`?

Comment: Try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so it outputs all the commands as it executes them. Then check your email for the output.

Comment: most likely curl isn't on your path when you use cron.  Either specify the full path or set your path in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Barman said, it works if you change `more` with `cat`:

Change this line:

```
last_ip=$(more /tmp/last_ip_check.txt)
```

To this:

```
last_ip=$(cat /tmp/last_ip_check.txt)
```

... and wait for the next execution of the script.

I don't know the reason, but as `more` is a pager, I believe `cat` is *more correct* to use in this case.

However, if I test both results and `diff` them, I get no differences:

```
jim@debian:~$ cat /tmp/last_ip_check.txt
1xx.1xx.2xx.1xx
jim@debian:~$ more /tmp/last_ip_check.txt
1xx.1xx.2xx.1xx
jim@debian:~$ cat /tmp/last_ip_check.txt > a
jim@debian:~$ more /tmp/last_ip_check.txt > b
jim@debian:~$ diff a b
```

Why is that, I don't know...

Comment: thank you jim and barmar that fixed it. I totally spaced that and start assuming it was a env issue. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: Since this is bash, you could save a few precious microseconds and use `last_ip=$(</tmp/last_ip_check.txt)`